# Modify value before I display it in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, lambda

I have a feeds table

```
Id  Message     Created
1   aaa         2016-02-25 12:18:51
2   bbb         2016-02-24 12:18:51
3   ccc         2015-02-25 12:18:51
```

I can get all the values like this

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var feeds = db.Feeds.ToList();

            return View(feeds);
        }
    }
```

I have created a class that change date from datetime to e.g "1 day ago". And this works fine

```
var myTime = DateExtension.TimeAgo(DateTime.Parse("2016-02-25 12:18:51"));
```

I want to modify all the dates in `feed` with help of `DateExtension.TimeAgo` before I return in to the view. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a view model and populate it from your feeds, but apply your transformation to the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
return View(
    feeds.Select(x=>
    new Feed{
       Id=x.Id, 
       Message=x.Message, 
       Created=DateExtension.TimeAgo(DateTime.Parse(x.Created))
   }).toList());
```

where Feed your class, with the same fields

Comment: Error message: `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The entity or complex type 'ThisIsMyProject.Models.Feed' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.` When I run the project, not in code view.

Comment: did you get all items like this:  var feeds = db.Feeds.ToList(); before call my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use FeedDisplayModel class in your view

```
public class Class1TestController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var feeds = db.Feeds.Select(itm=>new FeedDisplayModel(itm)).ToList();

            return View(feeds);
        }
    }

}
class Feed
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Message { get; set;}

}
class FeedDisplayModel : Feed
{
    public string Ago { get { return Created.TimeAgo(); } }

    public FeedDisplayModel(Feed itm){
        this.Created=itm.Created;
        this.Id=itm.Id;
        this.Message=itm.Message;
    }
}

public static class DateExtension
{
    public static string TimeAgo(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return "your implementation of ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess I'am doing wrong in the view. I get this error message when I compile. "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Projectxx.Models.Feed]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ProjectxxViewModels.FeedDisplayModel'."

I have this in my view

`@model Projectxx.ViewModels.FeedDisplayModel`
 
`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Ago)`

Comment: Off course you should use projections, i modified Feed, and FeedDisplayModel classes and Index functon